# Can we manipulate gravitation?

Tags: gravity, gravitational-waves

When I studied general relativity, my teacher said that what we knew today about gravitation was no better than what we had already known since Newton's time, because so far we could only propose theory about gravitation, not manipulating it like we could with electromagnetic. So I would like to ask this question: can we manipulate gravitation like we manipulate electromagnetic? Does Einstein's theory give us a key to turn the mass of the elephant to the mass of an ant? We just discover gravitational wave (strictly, the result isn't peer-reviewed, but let's assume that it is correct), will we be able to create one someday?

Extended question: can we manipulate strong and weak interactions?

---

Of course we don't have tensors in Newton's law. What I mean is even though we can describe gravitation better than before, and we have satelline and GPS, we still can't create gravitational waves.

Comment: Not only is this question unclear, it is arguably non-mainstream physics, and that last question also makes it too broad.

Comment: The results from the discoveries of gravitational waves *have* been peer-reviewed, and have garnered a Nobel Prize. But this question is definitely non-mainstream physics. And we can manipulate gravity just like we can manipulate electromagnetism - what makes you think we can't?

Comment: I think you may not have heard your teacher correctly - general relativity, the subject you were studying, is an updated theory of gravity.  Why would he tell you that we had no better knowledge about gravitation since Newton **while teaching you better knowledge about gravitation**?

Comment: it just an extended question. The aim of it is kicking the curiosity, not really asking a question. You don't need to answer it. Also, what point do you think it is unclear? @JamalS

Comment: @HDE226868 oh, then I miss that information. For your question, I have already stated in my question: "Does Einstein's theory give us a key to turn the mass of the elephant to the mass of an ant? "

Comment: The answer to that is no, because it would violate conservation of mass.

Comment: General relativity gives us the GPS, so Newton is not enough. Btw, you can't modify the mass of an elephant to the mass of an ant, the same way you can't modify the charge of an electron.

Comment: @Brionius see my update

Comment: @HDE226868 see my update. Also thanks for your "no" XD

Comment: @Ooker We can create gravitational waves, just weak ones - see Brionius' answer.

Comment: @jinawee see my update

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a sense, we can manipulate gravity just as well as we can manipulate EM fields.  Take the nearest object with mass, and wave it around - congratulations, you just broadcasted a gravitational wave.  Hey, wave it around, then stop, then wave it again, then stop, then wave it for longer, then stop.  You just sent a message in Morse code via gravitational waves!

The reason we **don't** generally manipulate gravity as we do EM forces is because gravitation is extraordinarily weak compared to the EM force.  No one is going to pick up your gravitational wave message, because the antenna required would be so unbelievably sensitive that no one has figured out how to build it yet.  Also, EM forces have a neat advantage in that electric charge can be negative, whereas there is no negative gravitational charge, as far as we know.  This allows for some very neat EM effects that we've taken advantage of.

As for your elephant question, that's an unfair comparison - turning the mass of an elephant into the mass of an ant violates mass conservation.  You can't do that, just like you can't violate electric charge conservation - if you have a large amount of electric charge, you can't just make it disappear, unless you remove it by allowing a current to flow.  And that's a lame trick - I could remove chunks of elephant until only the mass of an ant remained, but you wouldn't be impressed, and it would be an enormous mess.

Comment: Ah, I get it. We cannot manipulate it **in human scale**.

Comment: *the antenna required would be so unbelievably sensitive that no one has figured out how to build it yet.* We're hoping that [LIGO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) or [LISA/eLISA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Interferometer_Space_Antenna) is going to pick up something ;)

Comment: Yeah, me too!  But probably not sensitive enough to detect someone waving a coffee cup around in Morse code :)

Comment: This answer is largely obsolete. Now that we've detected gravitational waves, a number of papers have been published on how to go about manipulating them (no a tiny scale for now of course).